# Как соединить два div-a линией в приложении с drag & drop

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня есть приложение, написанное с помощью React-dnd, окно, в котором я могу свободно перемещать блоки. Проблема в том, что нужно соединять эти блоки линиями (стрелочками). Находил много вариантов в интернете, но у меня линии должен делать сам пользователь. Это не должна быть анимация или статическая линия, нужно чтобы пользователь мог соединить прямой линией два любых блока, где бы они не находились, и так же мог линии убирать, если они ему не нужны.
Буду благодарен за любые варианты. Смотрел примеры с canvas, svg, разными библиотеками, как например jsPlumb, но нигде не видел примера, где прямые линии проводит сам пользователь своей рукой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набросал примитивный пример на SVG, где можно от одного квадрата провести линию к другому. До идеала доводить не стал, основная идея думаю понятна.

```js
let from = document.querySelector('.from'),
    to = document.querySelector('.to'),
    mousePressed = false,
    pointFrom,
    pointTo,
    svg;

from.addEventListener( 'mousedown', e => {
    mousePressed = true;
    pointFrom = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
    };
});

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', e => {
    if( !mousePressed ) return;
    pointTo = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
    };
    updateLine();
});

document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', e => {
    if( !mousePressed ) return;
    mousePressed = false;
});

function updateLine(){
    if(svg) svg.remove();
    
    let width = pointTo.x - pointFrom.x,
        height = pointTo.y - pointFrom.y;
    
    svg = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg' );
    svg.style.left = pointFrom.x + 'px';
    svg.style.top = pointFrom.y + 'px';
    svg.setAttribute( 'width', pointTo.x - pointFrom.x );
    svg.setAttribute( 'height', pointTo.y - pointFrom.y );
    svg.setAttribute( 'viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}` );
    
    let path = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path' );
    path.setAttribute( 'stroke', 'red' );
    path.setAttribute( 'd', `M 0,0 L ${width},${height}` );
    
    svg.appendChild(path);
    
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
}
```

```css
.from, .to {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
}

.from {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.to {
  left: 200px;
  top: 30px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="from"></div>
<div class="to"></div>
```